# how to find & delete folder with a certain with find

Tags: backup, find, pipe

I have a drive with daily backups (twice a day) and need to delete a folder in each backup which is pretty deep into a folder structure.

> /mnt/backup/backup/[yymmdd_hhmm/backup-clients/[username]/

would `sudo find /mnt/backup/backup/ -type d -name [username] | rm -r` do that job?

Comment: find has a "-delete" action

Comment: Why exactly do you need `find`?  Have you tried `rm -rf /mnt/backup/backup/[yymmdd_hhmm[/backup-clients/[username]/` or, depending on your needs, maybe `rm -rf /mnt/backup/backup/*/backup-clients/[username]/` ?

Comment: @guiverc although iirc it won't delete non-empty directories, so perhaps not so useful here

Comment: I need to find the all folders named [username] at that particular level of the folder hierarchy. Maybe I wans't clear enough. **This needs to be a automated process. There are many, many versions (incremental rsync backups) of that [username] folder, so manually deleting anything is not workable**

Answer (score 2):

You want to use find's `-exec` option, `-exec rm -r {} +`. The `+` in the end groups the arguments into bigger batches, which means there will not be a separate `rm` process for each result, but they will be grouped into bigger chunks, resulting in lower CPU usage.

First run the `find` without the `-exec`, so that you can quickly make sure that the arguments that will be passed to `rm -r` are correct:

```
find /mnt/backup/backup/ -name "[username]" -type d
```

If everything looks fine, go ahead:

```
find /mnt/backup/backup/ -name "[username]" -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

Comment: sounds all logical, thx. It seems to take forever though. is that how it' is supposed to be? like I was running the 'blind' command (without the `-exec` part) for an hour or so and still it was not yet finished. Is `find` just that slow?

Comment: No, not really, it should be pretty fast. I suppose your "username" folder is quite frequent, then results should start to appear within seconds even on rotational disks. Can you see the `find` process generating IO activity (you can check with `atop`: start `atop`, press `1` for it to show per-second aggregates, `d` to see disk activity per process, and `t` to refresh the view)?